# HEROKU: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static/images'

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to deplay my app on heroku and am having issues with file dir
ERROR:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static/images'
```

current code

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(basedir, 'static/images')
```

any idea how can i solve the issue?
the folder order
[the folder order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tum4.png)

I tried to change the path to

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'app/static/images'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '../static/images'
```

and still was getting the same issue